# Which GCC version do I have on my OS X Sierra

Tags: python, gcc

When I type `gcc -v`, I get :

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9-20141029/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

So my gcc version is 4.9.2
However, when I try to install gcc again by typing : `brew tap homebrew/versions; brew install gcc --without-multilib`

I get :

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 3 taps (homebrew/core, homebrew/science, homebrew/versions).
==> New Formulae
git-quick-stats                 homebrew/science/med-file       ktmpl
==> Updated Formulae
aha                             homebrew/science/bowtie         mpd
akka                            homebrew/science/cdo            mysql-cluster
arangodb                        homebrew/science/matplotlib     no-more-secrets
buku                            homebrew/science/packmol        nvm
bullet                          homebrew/science/paraview       protobuf-swift
casperjs                        homebrew/science/pymol          qca
certigo                         imagemagick ✔                   ringojs
chicken                         imagemagick@6                   rust
cjdns                           jenkins                         skinny
coffeescript                    jigdo                           sqldiff
compcert                        jump                            sqlite-analyzer
crystal-lang                    kobalt                          svtplay-dl
dbhash                          libhdhomerun                    swiftgen
digdag                          libphonenumber                  vim
direnv                          libsigsegv                      wakatime-cli
elixirscript                    mapserver                       wolfssl
embulk                          mecab-jumandic                  yank
geoserver                       mkvtoolnix                      yaz
gitlab-ci-multi-runner          mosquitto
==> Deleted Formulae
bip                             homebrew/versions/openssl101    probatron4j
edelta                          lcab                            rtpbreak
esound                          malaga

Updating Homebrew...
Warning: gcc-6.3.0_1 already installed
```

This output says at the end that I have gcc 6.3 . 
Am I working with gcc 4.9.2 or gcc 6.3 ?

P.S : If you are interested in why I executed the brew tap & brew install commands, it is because I am trying to install xgboost in python. In [the github repo of xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/python-package), they're advising to run the above commands before installation to get the latest g++ compiler.

Comment: Have you tried looking around the file system for a GCC 6.3 installation? For example in `/usr/local` or `/opt`? Where is GCC 4.9 installed? Maybe `gcc` as a command is an alias or a soft link that can easily be changed?

Comment: `which gcc` provides `/usr/local/bin/gcc`. However, my `/usr/local/bin` folder contains many files with the name gcc-*. I have gcc, gcc-4.8 and gcc-6, plus the files gcc-ar, gcc-ar-4.8, gcc-ar-6, gcc-n-, gcc-nm-4.8, gcc-nm-6, gcc-ranlib, gcc-ranlib-4.8, gcc-ranlib-6. The gcc 6.3 is the file `/usr/local/bin/gcc-6`

Comment: It looks like you have *three* installations of GCC. Do you really *need* all three? Can't you remove one or the other? And have you tried searching for e.g. `mac os brew gcc change default`? It seems to give plenty of results. Or just do e.g. `export CC=gcc-6` or something similar before you retry your installation? Or as I said previously, check if `/usr/local/bin/gcc` is a *symbolic link* and change it to point to `gcc-6` instead?

Comment: Now my question is how do I make gcc-6 my default compiler ?

Comment: No, I don't need all versions. I would like to stick with the latest version (6.3). I do not have any experience with symbolic links. How do I check if  `/usr/local/bin/gcc` is a symbolic link and how can I change it to point to gcc-6 ?

Comment: It would be nice also to remove all the old gcc versions before 6.3

Comment: Well, I think I can do `cd /usr/local/bin; rm gcc;ln -s gcc-6 gcc` . But what about the files `gcc-ar`,  `gcc-nm` ,and `gcc-ranlib`. Can I remove them too without putting anything at risk ?

Answer (score -1):

To address your question "Am I working with gcc 4.9.2 or gcc 6.3"

You are still working with gcc 4.9.2.

How can you make gcc-6 your default compiler? See below:

```
sudo ln -s <path-to>/gcc-6 <path-to>/gcc
```

## Reload and verify

Now exit the terminal session and open a new terminal (so the links update) and type `gcc -v` and see if the version is now the latest.

## Other related tools

NOTICE: You may also wish to update `c++ -> c++-6`, `g++ -> g++-6`, and `cpp -> cpp-6` in a similar fashion, just repeat the above step for each in turn, ALWAYS BACKUP in case something goes wrong so you can undo everything if necessary.

## NOTE:

If you get a "Operation not permitted" warning and you are using El Capitan or newer version of Mac OS X please see this question/answer on how to disable the security feature that is preventing you from making changes to /usr/bin directory:

https://superuser.com/questions/933019/sudo-cant-create-file-in-usr-bin-in-el-capitan